# Understanding `\pdfbookmark`

Tags: bookmarks

I am trying to understand the `\pdfbookmark[level]{text}{name}` macro. Here are my questions:

1. Is it defined in the LaTeX core? Where can I see the code?
2. Where do I find the documentation?
3. I happen to be using `hyperref`, and `hyperref.sty` has this: `\newcommand\pdfbookmark[3][]{}`, which basically means 3 args (1 optional, 2 mandatory), empty body. What is this doing?
4. What is the `level`?

(Note: I am a novice in LaTeX, so would appreciate simpler answers, if possible.)

Comment: Slight correction: `\newcommand\pdfbookmark[3][]{}` means 3 args, _1 optional arg_, 2 mandatory args.

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\pdfbookmark` it is a hyperref command. The definition in hyperref.sty is a dummy, the real definitions are in the various backend files, e.g. `hpdftex.def` (for pdflatex) contains

```
\renewcommand\pdfbookmark[3][0]{%
  \Hy@writebookmark{}{#2}{#3.#1}{#1}{toc}%
  \hyper@anchorstart{#3.#1}\hyper@anchorend
}
```

The level allows to move up and down in the tree. With the `name` argument hyperref will create a target, so the name should be unique. You must compile the document twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{a section bookmark}

\newpage
A\pdfbookmark[1]{text A}{targetA}

\newpage
B\pdfbookmark[2]{text B}{targetB}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more options to create bookmarks, use the bookmark package. It has more powerful interfaces and requires also only one compilation.

Comment: UlrikeFischer, that helped a lot, thank you!

So basically:
 1. `\section` was automatically bookmarked by `\hyperref`. Some internal anchor-name must have been created.
 2. I can give any `name` (anchor-name), it just creates an anchorpoint at that place in the document.

I realize I had made a mistake earlier. Since I wasn't compiling twice, I was not able to see the changes I had made to the `text`/`name`. So my question 5 is wrong, I will delete it.

I will try out the `bookmark` package.

Answer (score 2):

Based on UlrikeFischer's explanation, I tried the following just to experiment. In case it helps anyone, posting it here. And do not forget to compile twice if using `hyperref` for pdfbookmarks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Section Bookmark}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Text A}{targetA} A
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[1]{Text B}{targetB} B
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[2]{Text C}{targetC} C
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[2]{Text D}{targetD} D
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[4]{Text E}{targetE} E Skipped Level
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[3]{Text F}{targetF} F
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[1]{Text G}{targetG} G
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[2]{Text H}{targetH} H
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Text I}{targetI} I
\end{document}
```

[image: hyperref Snapshot]

And here's how `bookmark` package works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    
\section{Section Bookmark}
    
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetA}{}
\bookmark[level=0,dest=targetA]{Text A} A
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetB}{}
\bookmark[level=1,dest=targetB]{Text B} B
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetC}{}
\bookmark[level=2,dest=targetC]{Text C} C
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetD}{}
\bookmark[level=2,dest=targetD]{Text D} D
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetE}{}
\bookmark[level=4,dest=targetE]{Text E} E Skipped Level
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetF}{}
\bookmark[level=3,dest=targetF]{Text F} F
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetG}{}
\bookmark[level=1,dest=targetG]{Text G} G
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetH}{}
\bookmark[level=2,dest=targetH]{Text H} H
\newpage
\hypertarget{targetI}{}
\bookmark[level=0,dest=targetI]{Text I} I
\end{document}
```

[image: bookmark Snapshot]